# Puzzle hidden in Hannah Fry's Hello World

Tags: cipher, treasure-hunt

Hanna Fry announced today that she hid a puzzle in the cover of her book—[via twitter](https://twitter.com/FryRsquared/status/1074966449687543808)

The initial clue seems to be a binary encoding of some ASCII. I was hoping to start a thread towards finding a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Next step after Dorrulf's observation:

> Typing commands into the console mostly returns random gibberish, but every once in a while the message will result in returning words that you've previously typed, plus another word. As it turns out, the permutation order of the words that you've previously typed is fixed.
>
>  Furthermore, it turns out that this extra word has the same length as the number of words you typed previously, allowing us to reorder this word. For example, you might recieve `deans (the 5th word you typed) (the 2nd word you typed) (the 4th word you typed) (the 1st word you typed) (the 3rd word you typed)`. We can then rearrange the added word, `deans`, to get the string `SEND A`.
>
>  Continuing in this fashion (where any number is replaced by the n-th word you typed):
>  - `8 7 6 10 9 menial 11` yields `N EMAIL`
>  - `12 14 sat 13` yields `STA`
>  - `22 20 21 15 19 16 whetting 17 18` yields `TING THE W`
>  - `24 23 rod 25` yields `ORD`
>  - `28 26 ufo 27` yields `FOU`
>  - `nod 29 31 30` yields `ND O`
>  - `33 pang 34 32 35` yields `N PAG`
>  - `38 36 wet 37` yields `E TW`
>  - `41 40 39 tao` yields `O AT`
>  - `45 43 shatter 47 42 46 44 48` yields `THE STAR`
>  - `52 loft 50 51 49` yields `T OF L`
>  - `56 57 53 54 55 twine` yields `INE TW`
>  - `60 ten 58 59` yields `ENT`
>  - `68 64 62 70 63 66 69 65 67 noteworthy 61` yields `Y TWO TO HNRE`
>  - `82 81 80 73 78 79 77 71 76 75 annehathaway 72 74` yields `HAEYW AT HANNA`
>  - `89 thyford 83 86 84 88 85 87` yields `HFRY DOT`
>  - `91 95 94 92 93 90 96 outdock` yields `CO DOT UK`
>
>  Or, parsed better, **Send an email stating the word found on page 2 at the start of line 22 to hnreaeyw@hannahfry.co.uk.**
>
>  Unfortunately, actually performing this step appears to probably require the book.
>
>  (One last observation, HNREAEYW is an anagram of ANYWHERE, so that might be either be a) the first location desired by the puzzle (as the author had stated that they had rescrambled the puzzle contents once already), or b) the actual location. Who knows.)

Comment: very nice, I was struggling on what to do with the extra returned word.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because this was the final round of the puzzle, and several people won a prize after this step. In that way, it's a solution.

Answer (score 6):

cool. Thanks for letting us know!

Partial:

> Binary from book cover:
>  0101001001100101011000010110110001101100011110010011111100100000
>  0100111101101000001000000110000101101100011100100110100101100111
>  0110100001110100001000000111010001101000011001010110111000111010
>  0010000001101000011001010110110001101100011011110111000001110101
>  0111101001111010011011000110010101110111011011110111001001101100
>  0110010000101110011000110110111101101101
>  Translates to:
>  Really? Oh alright then: hellopuzzleworld.com

Comment: I have no idea on what to do once there...