# Used technique to solve web interface permutation used in linked answer

Tags: riddle, cipher, pattern

I would love to get to know how the user 'phenomist' came to his solution ([Link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/77612/67961)) from a technical point of view. Of course I did tried it on my own. I used an interceptor to catch the HTTP request sent to the server modified it fired it against the API. I got results but nothing of use. I did this because the web interface had issues and broke after my 957th input. After that the web interface died everytime at around 230. However, if I'm guessing correctly 'phenomist' must have triggered the web interface or API at least 9000 times to get every permutation. I'm eager to solve it on my own, get the results for myself but even with the solution I cant get it done because my technique seems wrong.

I would be happy if anyone or 'phenomist' himself could explain how he did permuted through the web interface.

*PS: To be honest it would be way better to add a comment to the initial answer of 'phenomist'. Since I have a question in regards to his solution in the answer. However, it seams to be my one and only possibility within this forum is to ask a question.*

Comment: Pinging @phenomist